# Is it possible to export names and respective owner list of github repository to a csv file?

Tags: github

I am trying to export the list of repositories and owners from a Github Org to a csv.
Could anyone have idea on how to export the data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would take a look at the GitHub REST API or GitHub cli. You will have to write a small script or integrate the REST calls into Excel or something like that, I doubt that there is a ready-made Webinterface where you can just download the CSV.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - will check that out and share the result.